# Operating system is crashing - not sure if hardware nor how to trace it

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, hardware-failure, freeze

Just mentioning some facts and hope you will have a clue

- I experienced these issues back when I had Windows 10 and experienced them again after an upgrade to Windows 11 - so unfortunately not a software issue (i think)
- Getting 0xc000012d agent errors every once in a while
- chkdsk + memory check (MemTest) went fine
- Run Windows Error Checking and nothing went wrong
- Got File System Error today for the first time
- Sometimes when waking my pc after sleeping mode the screen gets no audio input and I have to unplug and plug back the HDMI cable.
- Windows is crashing (freezing, not responding, Night Light option disabled and screen is bright again, agent errors sometimes, explorer process misbehaving, etc) after several hours, and I have to reset the computer to get it to work again - I still don't know what causes these crushes, it appears to be quite spontaneous.
- System details: https://postimg.cc/8jDZp2zJ - computer is about one and a half years old
- I have cleaned my computer with a compressed-gas thingy - didn't seem to work

Any pieces of advice would be appreciated

Comment: Did you completely reinstall windows or just do an upgrade to Windows 11? Just upgrading will not clear out "software issues" so that could well still be firmly on the table. A clean install could clear out incompatible or unreliable software. It could also be that you have a failing disk or an underpowered PSU.

Comment: See if the computer manufacturer has a Hardware Test App and use that to test all the hardware. Pay attention to memory and disk.

Comment: @Mokubai I did a completely clean install - how can i test PSU?

Comment: @John It is not a laptop, a custom-built desktop pc

Comment: Then you need to get hardware test apps for each major component.

Comment: Try running from a live USB, e.g., Win RE or Ubuntu Live. If that does **not** crash after a day or so, look to the HDD/SSD and/or Windows OS causing the issue.